# How to create a model with different price tags on different shirt sizes?

Tags: python, django

I created this simple model for product, but don't know how to set separate price for various product (e.g. shirt) sizes.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="products/%y/%m/%d/")
    cover_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="products/%y/%m/%d/")
    price = models.FloatField()
    digital = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=False)
```

then show it in template like:

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a [constructor](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/constructors-in-python/).

```
class Whatever:
    def __init__(self, price):
        self.price = price
        # etc...
```

This way you can assign values for each object.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean for example one product = one shirt, but one shirt has multiple sizes with diffrent prices but they are still the same product? If so, maybe this is will work?

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="products/%y/%m/%d/")
    cover_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="products/%y/%m/%d/")
    digital = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=False)
    sizes = models.ManyToManyField(Size)

class Size(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField()


#To create an instance use:
size1 = Size(name="XLL", price=30)
size1.save()

size2 = Size(name="S", price=25)
size2.save()

product1 = Product(....)
product1.save()
product1.sizes.add(size1)
product1.sizes.add(size2)
```